# Can you include type parameters when overloading operators in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I want to do something in the same spirit of this non-compiling code

```
public static B operator + (Func<A,B> f, A a) {
    return f (a);
}
```

It there a way to specify the types `A` and `B`? I've tried

```
public static B operator +<A,B> (Func<A,B> f, A a) {
    return f (a);
}
```

but its too good to be true.

Answer (score 2):

No, operators can't be generic in C#. You can overload operators within generic types, but the operators themselves can't have type parameters.

If you look at the syntax for user-defined operators in the C# spec (e.g. in section 10.10 of the C# 5 spec) you'll see that it doesn't have anywhere for type parameters (or type parameter constraints) to be added.